# Make seekbar touch area larger

Tags: java, android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I created a `Seekbar` that looks as follows:

[image]

The problem is that in order to move the circle I need to be very precise and hit exactly in the circle which makes it pretty hard to move it.

I had like to make the touch area of that circle bigger, so even if the user clicks somewhere around the circle it will still move the slide.

The code im using is:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sb_radius"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:max="400"
    android:min="1"
    android:progress="10"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/sb_style"
    android:splitTrack="false"
    android:thumb="@drawable/sb_thumb"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sb_text">
</SeekBar>
```

and the style:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <size
        android:height="10dp"
        android:width="10dp"
        />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorLightPurple" />
</shape>
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried increasing the height and adding padding?

Comment: I dont want to change the visualization of the circle, only the effective radius of it

Comment: Have you tried the Slider instead of Seekbar?

Comment: Not sure I understood your comment

Comment: @Ben You can use the [Slider](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Slider.md) component included in the Material Components Library instead of the Seekbar.

Answer (score -1):

You can just try to use padding, it would not change the visualization of the circle, and it would increase the touch area.

Comment: It would be better to add a sample code of how to use padding.

Answer (score -1):

You can customize the Seekbar style by creating a different layout for that.

The following is an example for the customised layout,

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sb_radius"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:max="400"
    android:min="1"
    android:progress="10"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_drawable_progress"
    android:splitTrack="false"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_drawable_thumb"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sb_text">
</SeekBar>
```

**drawable/seekbar_drawable_progress.xml** file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:color="#dadbdc" android:width="2dp" />
            <solid android:color="#b7b7b7"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:clipOrientation="horizontal" android:gravity="left">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke android:color="#C24C47" android:width="2dp" />
                <solid android:color="#D83731"/>
                <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**drawable/seekbar_drawable_thumb.xml** file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#585eff"/>
            <stroke android:color="#99c8f7" android:width="3dp"/>
            <size android:height="30dp" android:width="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Result:

[image]